scipy 'minimize' with method='trust-constr' raises ValueError('expected square matrix')
I am trying to solve constrained optimization problems using scipy.optimize.minimize with method='trust-constr'.
My problems typically involve both equality and inequality nonlinear constraints. For instance, let's say I want to solve the following problem
minimize x4 -7/4x3 -1/2x2 + 27/16*x + 23/16
subject to
-x <= -1/2, sin(x)=0, cos(2x + pi/2)=0
I have tried with the following program:
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym
from scipy.optimize import minimize, NonlinearConstraint


def jac_lambda(f, variables):
    jac_mat = sym.Matrix([[f.diff(s) for s in variables]])
    jac_lambdify = sym.lambdify([variables], jac_mat, 'numpy')
    return lambda X, *args: jac_lambdify(X)[0]


def hess_lambda(f, variables):
    hess_mat = sym.Matrix([[f.diff(s1).diff(s2) for s2 in variables] for s1 in variables])
    hess_lambdify = sym.lambdify([variables], hess_mat, 'numpy')
    return lambda X, *args: hess_lambdify(X)


def wrap_fn(expr, symbols):
    fun = sym.lambdify([symbols], expr, 'numpy')
    jac = jac_lambda(expr, symbols)
    hes = hess_lambda(expr, symbols)
    return fun, jac, hes


def main():
    f_sym = sym.sympify("x**4 + -7/4*x**3 + -1/2*x**2 + 27/16*x + 23/16")
    cc_sym = [
        sym.sympify("-x <= -1/2"),
        sym.Eq(sym.sympify("sin(x)"), 0),
        sym.Eq(sym.sympify("cos(2*x + 1/2*pi)"), 0)
    ]
    symbols = ["x"]
    constraints = []
    for c in cc_sym:
        left, right = c.args
        fun, jac, hess = wrap_fn(left, symbols)

        if c.func == sym.Eq:
            domain = (right, right)
        elif c.func == sym.LessThan:
            domain = (-sym.oo, right)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Only equality and less than constraints are supported")
        constraint = NonlinearConstraint(fun, *domain, jac=jac, hess=hess)
        constraints.append(constraint)

    fun, jac, hess = wrap_fn(f_sym, symbols)
    x0 = np.zeros(len(symbols))
    res = minimize(fun, x0, method='trust-constr', jac=jac, hess=hess, constraints=constraints)
    print(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


where I am using sympy to manipulate expressions and compute the exact Jacobians and Hessians.
However, this raises the following stacktrace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mypath/examples/minimize_trust_constr.py", line 54, in <module>
    main()
  File "/mypath/examples/minimize_trust_constr.py", line 49, in main
    res = minimize(fun, x0, method='trust-constr', jac=jac, hess=hess, constraints=constraints)
  File "/mypath/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 725, in minimize
    res = _minimize_trustregion_constr(fun, x0, args, jac, hess, hessp,
  File "/mypath/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_trustregion_constr/minimize_trustregion_constr.py", line 528, in _minimize_trustregion_constr
    _, result = tr_interior_point(
  File "/mypath/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_trustregion_constr/tr_interior_point.py", line 321, in tr_interior_point
    z, state = equality_constrained_sqp(
  File "/mypath/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_trustregion_constr/equality_constrained_sqp.py", line 81, in equality_constrained_sqp
    Z, LS, Y = projections(A, factorization_method)
  File "/mypath/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_trustregion_constr/projections.py", line 405, in projections
    Z = LinearOperator((n, n), null_space)
  File "/mypath/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/_interface.py", line 584, in __init__
    self._init_dtype()
  File "/mypath/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/_interface.py", line 182, in _init_dtype
    self.dtype = np.asarray(self.matvec(v)).dtype
  File "/mypath/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/_interface.py", line 236, in matvec
    y = self._matvec(x)
  File "/mypath/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/_interface.py", line 593, in _matvec
    return self.__matvec_impl(x)
  File "/mypath/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_trustregion_constr/projections.py", line 196, in null_space
    aux2 = scipy.linalg.solve_triangular(R, aux1, lower=False)
  File "/mypath/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/linalg/_basic.py", line 336, in solve_triangular
    raise ValueError('expected square matrix')
ValueError: expected square matrix

This error is not raised when I only use inequality constraints (since the equality_constrained_sqp is not invoked), or when I only use one equality constraint.
I could not find much documentation apart from
this link and this link, so I wonder whether I am calling the function with correct parameters.
What causes the problem and how can I fix it?

The parameter sparse_jacobian and lines in the traceback indicate that it's setting up the constraints as a sparse linear equation iterative solution. There's no indication that your lambdified sympy expressions are involved, but they don't make understanding your code easy.  It's a complicated setup, and a complicated minimize method.

Here's my attempt at minimizing the code while still getting the same error: https://gist.github.com/nickodell/96a26bc739b3eed58eb37c90be8a9049 Seems the necessary conditions are having two equality constraints on one variable. The hess, jac, sympy stuff are all irrelevant. Looks like a bug to me.

Although, it's worth noting that even if this is a bug in trust-constr, what you're doing is never going to work very well. If you write a constraint like sin(x) = 0, then the solver will never try any areas other than x = 0, because as soon as it moves away from 0, it gets penalized. It is a local optimizer.

Hi, thanks for investiganting a smaller example raising the same error. I have opened an issue on scipy's github. As for your second point, you are right in the sense that x=0 wil be a local minimizer anyway. I think that a solution would be to choose another starting point and minimize from there, using a basin-hopping-like approach.
